# Unnamespaced routes within namespaced routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing

I have several namespaced routes in an app.  Here's a sample

```
namespace "battles" do
  resources :teams do
    resources :comments, :module => "comments", :controller=>'comments'
  end
end
```

My problem is that all my resources with comments route to the comments/comments controller, but because :teams is in the battles namespace, then the app tries to route to battles/comments/comments

Is there a way to specify that the nested comment resource should route to the comments/comments controller, not the battle/comments/comments controller.

Comment: If you don't want comments to be in the namespace, then why don't you just move it out? Are your comments routes actually nested inside teams? (It doesn't look like it from your description).

Comment: Comments are all tied to a commentable (which in this case is teams).  I need to know that I am commenting on a team vs something else (so all my commentables have nested comment routes).  My comments controller has a find_commentable method that looks at the previous part of the URL to figure what type of model to load.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
     scope :module => "battles" do  
        resources :teams do
         resources :comments, :module => "comments", :controller=>'comments'   
       end 
    end
```

Comment: That causes the route to expect to be in the Battle::Comments module

Answer (score 0):

I gave up and just created a Battle::Comments controller.  It results in code duplication so it's not ideal.

Comment: You could also add this line to the end of your Comments controller: 

Battles::CommentsController = CommentsController

Also not ideal, but better than code duplication.